# Vim search and replace selected text

Tags: vim

Let's say we have a text, and I enter visual mode and select some text. How do I quickly do a search for the highlighted text and replace it with something else?

Comment: This question demonstrates one of the most frustrating shortcomings of vim. This job could be done in a couple of seconds in any graphical editor. But as all the answers provided show we have to jump through many hoops before we can get vim to do the same.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Try execute the following or put in into your `.vimrc`

```
vnoremap <C-r> "hy:%s/<C-r>h//gc<left><left><left>
```

By pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> in visual mode, you will be prompted to enter text to replace with. Press <kbd>enter</kbd> and then confirm each change you agree with <kbd>y</kbd> or decline with <kbd>n</kbd>.

This command will override your register `h` so you can choose other one (by changing `h` in the command above to another lower case letter) that you don't use.

Comment: Where do you add this ? ... sorry i am really new to vim

Comment: If you under unix like system you have ~/.vimrc file. Put the given line to this file and restart vim.

Comment: If you omit the `c` in `gc`, replace is done at once in the whole buffer. If you made a mistake and want to revert it, just type `u` in command mode. I like this approach better than confirming each one of the replacements (that happens with the `c` modifier).

Comment: `vmap * y:let @/ = @"<CR>`
selected is highlighted.

Comment: User dmd has posted [an improvement to this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5925566/343302) below, which does not overwrite the `h` register.

Comment: What's the goal of `<left><left><left>`?

Comment: @aymericbeaumet to get the cursor between the two forward slashes, that way the replace word can be easily typed.

Comment: Note that if you take @Niloct's suggestion about removing the `c` from `gc`, you'll also have to remove one of the `<left>`'s from the end of the line.

Comment: Note that if your concern with the `gc` is that you hit `y` too many times, you can hit `a` instead to confirm all replacements, or `q` to say no to the rest of them. for more fun commands read `:help :s_c`

Comment: What are the keystrokes to do it manually, without editing my `.vimrc` file?

Comment: This is working great, but if the visual selection occurs more than once on the line it is not being substituted. Any tips for that?

Comment: Thank you, I ended up making slight adjustments to make it work for myself:
`vnoremap <C-r> "hy:%s/<C-r>h//g<left><left>`

Comment: this does not work when you have special chars to escape, i.e. http://something.com, the // must be escaped

Comment: I suggest that add `\V` after `hy:%s/`, because search text like this may want a text match insteam regex match

Answer (score 53):

This one works also (at least for selections in a single line / selections that don't contain any special characters)

- select the text in visual mode
- yank the text with `y`
- `:s/<C-r>0/`

`0` is the yank register.

As other people mentioned, there are faster ways to do this, but if you've just started learning Vim (like me), this is one of the 'generic' ways.

//edit: I've just realized that the 'register' approach will fail if there are characters like tabs or newlines or `/` characters in the selection (I'd have to manually process those characters somehow in order for the `:s` command to work):

[image]

Comment: It's very simple. Oh God, why it's not covered on the wiki. Come on... Thank you for the answer!

Comment: This is the ideal answer for those of us still on the early part of the Vim learning curve. I know customization is a strength, but I don't want to copy-paste a complex script into my vimrc and puzzle through how it fits together for a problem as simple as this. This answer taught me that ctrl-R dumps a register, which will be handy to remember in other contexts.

Comment: Regarding your last edit about special characters (I had slashes / in the path), you can simply use other separators (like * or |, what fits you better). This way I replaced a complex path in the entire file using stars * as separators with a command like ```:%s*<C-r>0*/Users/very/long/path/here/*gc```

Answer (score 48):

This quick and simple mapping search for visually highlighted text (without over-writing the h register) and without using the terminal dependant + register:

```
" search for visually hightlighted text
vnoremap <c-f> y<ESC>/<c-r>"<CR>
```

If you dont like the ctrl-f change it to your preference

Once the text is highlighted you can always do a `s`ubstitution simply by typing:

```
%s//<your-replacement-string>
```

... because a blank search on the `s` command uses the last searched for string.

Comment: When I use this in my vim configuration, `control+f` always selects the very next character as well as what I visually selected. Any ideas?

Comment: `%s//<your-replacement-string>` doesn't seem to work for highlighting something like `/tmp/file`. it just becomes `<your-replacement-string>/tmp/file`

Answer (score 34):

The accepted answer works great unless you have special characters in your visual selection. I hacked together two scripts ([Jeremy Cantrell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676600/vim-replace-selected-text/677918#677918)'s posted here & [Peter Odding](http://peterodding.com/code/vim/profile/autoload/xolox/escape.vim)'s) to make a command that will allow you to visual select a string that you want to find even if it has special regex characters in it.

```
" Escape special characters in a string for exact matching.
" This is useful to copying strings from the file to the search tool
" Based on this - http://peterodding.com/code/vim/profile/autoload/xolox/escape.vim
function! EscapeString (string)
  let string=a:string
  " Escape regex characters
  let string = escape(string, '^$.*\/~[]')
  " Escape the line endings
  let string = substitute(string, '\n', '\\n', 'g')
  return string
endfunction

" Get the current visual block for search and replaces
" This function passed the visual block through a string escape function
" Based on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676600/vim-replace-selected-text/677918#677918
function! GetVisual() range
  " Save the current register and clipboard
  let reg_save = getreg('"')
  let regtype_save = getregtype('"')
  let cb_save = &clipboard
  set clipboard&

  " Put the current visual selection in the " register
  normal! ""gvy
  let selection = getreg('"')

  " Put the saved registers and clipboards back
  call setreg('"', reg_save, regtype_save)
  let &clipboard = cb_save

  "Escape any special characters in the selection
  let escaped_selection = EscapeString(selection)

  return escaped_selection
endfunction

" Start the find and replace command across the entire file
vmap <leader>z <Esc>:%s/<c-r>=GetVisual()<cr>/
```

I've included this in my [vimrc](https://github.com/bryankennedy/vimrc) if that's more useful to anyone.

Comment: thanks for solution, combining multiple proposals, I ended up with the following: `vmap <C-r> <Esc>:%s/<c-r>=GetVisual()<cr>//g<left><left>` (which just replaces all in file)

Comment: Is a recursive `vmap` needed here? Anyway, thanks, this is a gem and looks like it is solving my https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/41421/how-to-grab-visual-selection-for-search-but-apply-the-appropriate-escapes 

Also, using ctrl+R is clever. I hadn't considered visual mode is in a different key binding space compared to normal mode

Answer (score 30):

From Vim 7.4, you can use the `gn` motion which selects regions of text that match the current search pattern.

After using `cgn` to change the text in currently selected match (or `dgn` to delete), in normal mode, you can use `.` to repeat the command and operate on the next match.

There's [an episode of Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/) showing this feature.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: This's also awesome. aside of colemik answer. Great one!

Comment: wow, it's like one of those secret you find when you browse deep to find a good solution, thanks!

Comment: Half a decade after, I add that this one is good because it can be used without requiring changes to the .vimrc, so, much more applicable during sessions on servers, what are vim's common ground. Very good.

Comment: Great answer, BUT, in NeoVim v0.8.2, if you expand the visual selection with `gn` and then hit `cgn`, it will jump into insert mode without waiting for `gn`. Hitting `n` and then `.` applies this manipulation to the following matches.

Answer (score 14):

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_a_visual_selection:

When text is visually selected, press : to enter a command. The command line will automatically enter the range:

```
:'<,'>
```

You can enter a command such as s/red/green/g to replace each red with green in all lines of the last visual selection. The command will appear as:

```
:'<,'>s/red/green/g
```

To repeat an Ex command over a previously selected block, use the : history. That is, press : then , then edit a previous command.

Comment: yes this replaces red with green *in the selected area* - very useful, but not what the op asked for.

Comment: @ErichBSchulz It actually does it on all selected lines.  So, even if only part of a line is selected, it will do it to the entire line.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't answer the OP question, but this does exactly answer my search "vim search and replace with visual selection", where I want to limit the search and replace to only the visual selection, which brings up this question

Answer (score 9):

Mykola Golubyev,
Thanks for the tip!  Following uses the "+" register which (depending on your terminal) already contains the highlighted text, saving from using the "h" register.

```
vnoremap <C-r> <Esc>:%s/<C-r>+//gc<left><left><left>
```

Comment: My VIM 7.0 on CentOS 5.x does not seem to have the + register. Is this a standard feature?

Comment: I note that I access the CentOS machine via Putty, and upon googling I see that + is the clipboard register. Putty does not seem to support that! So this answer is in fact terminal-dependent.

Comment: Hi, I tried your command but it is asking me to replace the occurences of specified text throughout all the file, and not just the selected text

Answer (score 8):

I was hoping there was a built in way in Vim to replace a word, without having to retype the word out in the first place. There is, although it will only work for text up to a word boundary character.

Once you've moused over the word, press `*` or `#` to highlight the word and jump to the next/previous location of it (if you don't want to change locations in the file, then press the opposite key to go back to the location you were just at).

Then just type:

`%s//<your-replacement-string>`

As mentioned in another person's answer, if `%s` receives a blank entry between the slashes, then it uses the previously searched for word. By pressing `*` or `#`, you're searching for the word under the cursor which makes it the most recently searched word.

In the end it's only six or seven keystrokes + length of replacement word to perform this and it requires no macro or editing of your `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 5):

I have this in my vimrc:

```
function! GetVisual() range
    let reg_save = getreg('"')
    let regtype_save = getregtype('"')
    let cb_save = &clipboard
    set clipboard&
    normal! ""gvy
    let selection = getreg('"')
    call setreg('"', reg_save, regtype_save)
    let &clipboard = cb_save
    return selection
endfunction

vmap <leader>z :%s/<c-r>=GetVisual()<cr>/
```

This will grab the visual selection and start a substitution command with it.

EDIT: I should point out that this does not work with multiline visual selections. While GetVisual() doesn't have a problem returning it, I'm not sure how to properly put it into the command line. If anyone has any tips on how I might do this, please comment.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers are good but they do not escape special characters. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6171215/5152114) of @brian kennedy shows a method to escape but it requires much code. In case of an URL for instance, escaping is mandatory or the search will stop on “:”.

As written in [vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text), you can do a oneliner to search and escape some characters. You can escape the characters you want, I chose to escape `/\:` :

```
vnoremap // y/\V<C-R>=escape(@",'/\:')<CR><CR>
```

With this map, I must press `//` in visual mode to search the currently selected text on the whole buffer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this out of the box. But lots of people like this feature, so there's tons of macros and such (I've added it myself). [**Here**](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text) is one you can add, for example; just press `*` to search for the next match on the visually selected text.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation on Mykola's answer. I like making substitutions starting from the current line to the end of the text, then from the beginning to the current line (essentially the loop starts from the current line instead of the beginning).

```
vnoremap <C-r> "hy:.,$s/<C-r>h//gc \|1,.&& <left><left><left><left><left><left><left><left><left><left><left>
```

First, the substitution is made from the current line to the end of the text `.,$`, then it is repeated from the beginning to the current line `\|1,.&&`. The 11 `<left>` put the cursor in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite short version of this is

vnoremap s/ y:s/"/

Then you can highlight a selection and just hit s/ to start a substitution command for it.

Comment: Didn't work for me, treated `"` as a literal. `<c-r>"` worked though

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rep to comment, so I'm adding yet another answer...

`vnoremap <C-r> "0y<Esc>:%s/<C-r>0//g<left><left>`

@dmd and @dotancohen: this worked for me without using up `"h` (explicitly uses 0, which is the last yank position anyway) and works with putty ssh -> mint (lmde); don't know about cent. Also uses @Niloct and @Nathan Friend comments to remove confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Example 1. Quote selection with stars, keep cursor at start of selection.

```
:%s,\%#\%V\_.*\%V/,**&**,c
```

Example 2. Pipe selected text with base64:

```
:%s!\%#\%V\_.*\%V!\=system("base64 -w 0",@")!c
```

Explanation LHS:

```
\%# matches cursor 
\%V matches inside the selection only
\_. matches any character.
\_.* matches beginning to end of selection.
```

Explanation RHS:

```
\=expr()  Replace match with result of expr() for each substitution.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Neovim, here is a cleaner Lua implementation of bryan kennedy's answer:

```lua
-- get contents of visual selection
-- handle unpack deprecation
table.unpack = table.unpack or unpack
function get_visual()
  local _, ls, cs = table.unpack(vim.fn.getpos('v'))
  local _, le, ce = table.unpack(vim.fn.getpos('.'))
  return vim.api.nvim_buf_get_text(0, ls-1, cs-1, le-1, ce, {})
end

vim.keymap.set("v", "<C-r>", function()
  local pattern = table.concat(get_visual())
  -- escape regex and line endings
  pattern = vim.fn.substitute(vim.fn.escape(pattern, "^$.*\\/~[]"),'\n', '\\n', 'g')
  -- send parsed substitution command to command line
  vim.api.nvim_input("<Esc>:%s/" .. pattern .. "//<Left>")
end)
```