# How can I comment a single line or a block of lines in Vim?

Tags: css, vim, comments

In a CSS file, this line is in more than 5 rules.

```
border: 1px solid black;
```

I want to comment this line like this:

```
/*border: 1px solid black;*/
```

Is there a shortcut to do this comment for all 5 occurrence?

Can I assign a key to comment a single line or a block of lines?

I don't want to search and replace this only line, i want to set a key so that when i hover a line and press that key, that line will be commented or selecting a line or selecting a block of line, if i press that key, that line or block of line will be commented.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest using a macro for this. Macros are automatically saved by Vim and available across sessions.

To record a macro type: `q<letter><commands>q`. Where `<letter>` is any letter from a-z and indicates the register in which the macro will be saved. After that you simply type the commands you wish to be recorded and finally press `q` again to stop recording.

In your case you could do the following. Press `q`, then press `a` to select the `a` register, next enter insert mode and enter the `/*` and `*/` at the beginning and end of a line. Press `q` again to stop recording.

Now simply move the cursor to any line and press `@a` to execute the macro on that line.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a regex for this?

```
:1,$s/border: 1px solid black;/\/*border: 1px solid black;\*\//
```

`1,$s` means, that your substitution should be done from line `1` to line `$` which is the last line. Keep in mind, that you have to escape characters like `*` or `/`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676600/vim-replace-selected-text) question on Stackoverflow you can put the following in your .vimrc

```
vnoremap <C-r> "hy:%s/\(<C-r>h\)/\/\*\1\*\//gc<left><left><left>
```

you now can visually mark a line and press <kbd>ctrl+r</kbd> which gives you the right regular expression. You're now asked line by line if you want to comment it and can do this by pressing <kbd>y</kbd>.

Comment: I don't want to search and replace this only line, i want to set a key so that when i hover a line and press that key, that line will be commented or selecting a line or selecting a block of line, if i press that key, that line or block of line will be commented.

Comment: Use backreferences to save typing. Also, you can use `%` instead of the range `1,$` at the beginning.

Comment: I don't want to search and replace.

Comment: Isn't that solved in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676600/vim-replace-selected-text

Comment: Why do you "not want to search and replace"? Is there anything wrong with that kind of approach?

Comment: Searching an replacing will be time consuming.

Answer (score 3):

You have to try [NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) plugin for VIM. IMHO this plugin is the best for this task.