# How to efficiently escape meta-characters in vim search

Tags: perl, vim

`Perl` provides [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function, as well as the possibility to surround strings using the `\Qlots-of-meta-characters\E` construct, to make sure that all the characters between `\Q` and `\E` are interpreted as literals.

Very often I search strings full of meta characters in Vim. It's counterproductive to escape every special character individually. Is there anything like `/\Qstring-to-search\E` in Vim, which would make life easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `/\Vstring-to-search`.

There are two caveats:

- `\` is special. You can still use all regex metacharacters by putting a `\` in front of them.
- There is no `\E` equivalent. `\V` affects the rest of the regex.

See `:help /\V`.

You could combine this with the code from the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/676619/1848654 as follows:

```
vnoremap <C-f> "hy/\V<C-r>=substitute(@h,'[\/]','\\&','g')<cr>
```

The idea is:

- Copy ("yank") the selected text into register `h`: `"hy`
- Start search mode: `/`
- Prefill the beginning of the regex: `\V`
- Insert the contents of a register: `<C-r>`
- Don't use a real register; take the result of evaluating an expression instead: `=`
- Our expression (terminated by `<cr>`) is: `substitute(@h,'[\/]','\\&','g')`

  - Take the contents of the `h` register: `@h`
  - Apply a substitution. Insert a `\` before every `\` and `/`: `substitute(...,'[\/]','\\&','g')`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! One of the downsides of '\' being special is that searching for `/\Vprintk("Error\n")` doesn't work, but probably I can live with that...

Comment: Does `/\Q...` also work? There's no need for a closing `\E` with that either.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca Yeah, you'll have to write `\Vprintk("Error\\n")` there.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks! The perl analogy becomes even more straightforward.

Comment: @melpomene I wonder if the approach described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/676619/2381750 could copy the selected text to command line with all special characters backslash-ed, which would overcome the limitations described in your answer.

Comment: @melpomene Almost perfect answer! What I'm *not* interested in is the find-replace topic touched in https://stackoverflow.com/a/676619/2381750 . Basically, `vnoremap <C-f> "hy:/\V<C-r>=substitute(@h,'[\/]','\\&','g')<cr>` works flawlessly for me. If you have 5min to tailor your answer to my needs, I'll happily select it as the right one. Thanks!