# Vim escape backslash paste

Tags: vim, escaping, backslash

I am having the following text in vim:

```
Hello, \/Good\/Bye.
```

Now I want to change it to:

```
Hello, -Good-Bye.
```

So I use: Visual Select, Yank the Line. then

```
%s/<Ctrl+R>+"/-/gc
```

When I push `CTRL+R+"` The line clones into the search, but It `\/` will not work. I need to change it to `\\/` . Is there a quick function or keystroke to automatically escape the chars? Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: [`\V`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50629050/7976758) disables all magic. [`escape()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871009/7976758) escapes metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

As phd wrote in comments, you can use `\V` and `escape()` to do it. For example, write the following function:

```
function! Regesc(text)
    return '\V' . escape(a:text, '/\')
endf
```

Then after yanking some text, use it like this:

`:%s/`<kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd>`=Regesc(@@)`<kbd>CR</kbd>`/-/gc`<kbd>CR</kbd>

This will display and run the following command, depending of what you yanked:

`:%s/\VHello, \\\/Good\\\/Bye./-/gc`

Answer (score 0):

You could use another delimiter after your visual selection

```
:'<,'>s,\%V\\/\%V,-,gc

\\ ......... scaped backslash
\%V ........ visual selection area
```

So you have to put your pattern `\\/` inside a visual delimiter